# Bind to ng-model of input as ng-click parameter of button

Tags: angularjs

If possible, how might I bind to a text input `ng-model` from a parameter sent in a button `ng-click`?

```
<input ng-model="joinToken">
<button ng-click="joinActivity({{ joinToken }})">Join</button>
```

I tried the above and it throws a parse syntax error because the value of `$scope.joinToken` doesn't exist yet, I think.

Comment: Thanks, @Pankaj-Parker. That worked.

Comment: glad to know that, thanks & cheers :-)